# Initiate login from Terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, login

Is it possible to login to another account from Terminal? I don't mean having a shell prompt as that user; I mean as if I went to the account switcher menu and changed using that.

Comment: What are you trying to do? A miox of apps running as different people on the screen?

Comment: @Mark No; I'm essentially looking for a way to switch users similar to the login screen. Like how you would go to the login screen and log in as a user you'd be taken to the desktop of that user. That but from Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Show the login screen (without logging out):

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend
```

Switch current user (replace 501 with the correct UID):

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -switchToUserID 501
```

(found at http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/2008/01/26/fast-user-switching-via-commandline/.)